# -moz-transform not behaving the same as -webkit-transform

Tags: css, firefox, transform

I have circular elements that I am filling with quarter-circles to show progression. In Safari, IE and Chrome, these look great and fill the circle as they're supposed to:

[image: Webkit]

However, when I open the same page in Firefox, the transformations are distorted:

[image: Firefox]

The transform code is exactly the same. What could be causing this?

```
mc c ftl, mc c ftr, mc c fbr, mc c fbl{
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
-moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
-ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
-o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
transform-origin: 100% 100%;

-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skewX(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg) skewX(0deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(0deg) skewX(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg) skewX(0deg);
transform: rotate(0deg) skewX(0deg);
}

mc c ftl:before, mc c ftr:before, mc c fbr:before, mc c fbl:before{
box-sizing: border-box;
display: block;
border: solid 10px navy;
width: 200%; 
height: 200%;
border-radius: 50%;

-webkit-transform: skewX(-0deg);
-moz-transform: skewX(-0deg);
-ms-transform: skewX(-0deg);
-o-transform: skewX(-0deg);
transform: skewX(-0deg);

content: '';

position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
}

mc c ftr
{
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) skewX(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg) skewX(0deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg) skewX(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg) skewX(0deg);
transform: rotate(90deg) skewX(0deg);
}

mc c fbr
{
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) skewX(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg) skewX(0deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg) skewX(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg) skewX(0deg);
transform: rotate(180deg) skewX(0deg);
}

mc c fbl
{
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) skewX(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(270deg) skewX(0deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(270deg) skewX(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(270deg) skewX(0deg);
transform: rotate(270deg) skewX(0deg);
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwkKb/1/)

---

### Update

So the issue appears to be with the width of the elements. Does firefox calculate width and height differently than webkit? Perhaps the border is accounted for in `width: 200%` in Webkit, but not so in Firefox. If I subtract `2*border-width` from the width and height, the circles fit in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Comment: A jsFiddle or similar would be very handy.

Comment: @alex Let me put one together

Comment: @alex Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/bwkKb/1/

Comment: I don't think `$(elm).find(":before").css("border", "10px solid red");` is gonna work.

Comment: @alex Yeah. I removed that; it's not important to this code anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add Firefox  vendor prefix in your css for `box-sizing`. I've checked it `Firefox 27` and its working..

Here is the ***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/bwkKb/2/)***.

```
mc c ftl:before, mc c ftr:before, mc c fbr:before, mc c fbl:before{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /*Added Mozilla Prefix*/
    display: block;
    border: solid 10px navy;
    width: 200%; 
    height: 200%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-0deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(-0deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-0deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(-0deg);
    transform: skewX(-0deg);
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
```